# Prevent removing leading zero when using case when and substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a variable like this

```
DECLARE @CODE NVARCHAR(10) = '09000:09502';
```

I need to split the `@CODE` variable into two variables and insert them into a temporary table for doing bulk insert.

But when I using 'CASE WHEN' inside my select statement, the value after split will remove the leading zero, '09000' will became '9000' (seem like those value is treat as number instead of string). Even I using CAST function, it is still not working.

I doing a little testing using this code:

```
DECLARE @CODE   VARCHAR(10) = '09000:09502';
DECLARE @Split1 VARCHAR(10) = '';
DECLARE @Split2 VARCHAR(10) = '';

SET @Split1 = CAST((CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', @CODE) > 0 
                            THEN LEFT(@CODE, CHARINDEX(':', @CODE) - 1)
                            ELSE -1 
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20))
SET @Split2 = LEFT(@CODE, 5);

PRINT(@Split1);
PRINT(@Split2);
```

The output I get is:

```
9000
09000
```

When I didn't using 'CASE WHEN', I can get the value what I want to, but I using 'CASE WHEN', the leading zero will be removed.

How can I preserve the leading zero value when I use `CASE WHEN` and `LEFT` function in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain why here `DECLARE @CODE   VARCHAR(10) = '09000:09502';` you try to put more than it holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All branches of a `CASE` statement must return the same data type. 
When you return `-1` at the else part, the value returned by this CASE is casted to integer so `09000` will turn to `9000`. 
You can change `-1` to `'-1'`.

```
DECLARE @CODE    VARCHAR(11) = '09000:09502';
DECLARE @Split1  VARCHAR(10) = '';
DECLARE @Split2  VARCHAR(10) = '';
SET @Split1      = CASE 
                     WHEN CHARINDEX(':',@CODE)>0 THEN LEFT(@CODE, CHARINDEX(':', @CODE)-1)
                     ELSE '-1' 
                   END
SET @Split2      = RIGHT(@CODE, LEN(@CODE)-CHARINDEX(':', @CODE));
PRINT(@Split1);
PRINT(@Split2);
```

This way you don't need the `CAST()` function. 
Also you declared `@CODE` as `VARCHAR(10)` and this truncated the last char. 
Change to `VARCHAR(11)`. 
Also I guess you want `@Split2` to be assigned the **right** 5 chars of `@CODE` and not the left as in your code.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=39051c3379d81692ef3ae4f391e1bb6b).

Comment: Thank for your help, finally I know where I did wrong. I use -1 because of after I split all my values I can do a quick check which row are contains -1 so I can skip the insertion.

Answer (score 1):

In your CASE statement, the `THEN` and `ELSE` statement's result data type should be same. But in your query the ELSE block's return result is `-1`, so it considering the output of the case statement is `INT`, so it remove the leading zero from the result and return as integer, and you are expecting the output as varchar only.

So if you are modify your `ELSE` block to `ELSE '' END` or `ELSE '-1' END` it will return your expected result as varchar(10).

Answer (score 1):

As @Arulkumar mentioned, it is because your case statement is returning an integer. I simplified your code a bit:

```
DECLARE @CODE    VARCHAR(10) = '09000:09502';
DECLARE @Split1  VARCHAR(10) = '';
DECLARE @Split2  VARCHAR(10) = '';

DECLARE @ColonIndex INT = CHARINDEX(':',@CODE)

SET @Split1      = CASE WHEN @ColonIndex > 0 THEN LEFT(@CODE, @ColonIndex-1)
                        ELSE '-1' END
SET @Split2      = LEFT(@CODE, 5);

PRINT(@Split1);
PRINT(@Split2);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I managed to solved this problem by follow his guide. Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just make your conversion impervious to the values, Here are some test cases:  The second query is the one you can use with just the two columns, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` as you see fit

```
DECLARE @Codes TABLE (Code VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @Codes (Code)
Values('09000:09502'),('090001:09502'),('090001:095022'),('0900022:09502'),
('090001:095021'),('0900055'),(':0900056'),('090003:'),(''),(':'),('::'),
('8:0900055'),(NULL);

DECLARE @Splitter VARCHAR(1) = ':';

SELECT 
    Code,
    CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) AS SplitPoint,
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 0 THEN 'NO splitter'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 1 THEN 'NO LEFT'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN 
            LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) - 1)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) IS NULL THEN 'OOPS'
        ELSE 'broken'
    END AS Split1
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 0 THEN Code 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 1 THEN RIGHT(Code,LEN(Code)- 1)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN 
          RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code )-1 -
                LEN(LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) - 1))
                )   
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) IS NULL THEN 'OOPS2'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN 'NO RIGHT'
        ELSE RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code)) + 'faile'
    END AS Split2
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 0 THEN ' no splitter'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 1 THEN ' =1'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN ' >1'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) IS NULL THEN 'OOPS2'
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN 'NO RIGHT'
        ELSE RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code)) + 'faile'
    END AS Split2By
FROM @Codes;

-- end code
    CREATE TABLE #MyTemp (Split1 VARCHAR(20),Split2 VARCHAR(20));

    INSERT INTO #MyTemp (Split1, Split2)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 0 THEN ''
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 1 THEN ''
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) - 1)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) IS NULL THEN Code
        ELSE Code -- 'broken'
    END AS Split1
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 0 THEN Code 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) = 1 THEN RIGHT(Code,LEN(Code)- 1)
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code )-1 - LEN(LEFT(Code, CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) - 1)))
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) IS NULL THEN Code
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@Splitter, Code) > 1 THEN ''
        ELSE Code -- 'fail'
    END AS Split2
FROM TableWithUnsplitCodes;

SELECT * FROM #MyTemp
-- WHERE --clause if you need to bypass any
```